# Landscape video to show on iPhone 5/6 portrait mode? How?

Tags: video

I have the following issue to solve: a video was captured in 1131x693px resolution (landscape mode). Now this video should be able to play on a mobile screen in **portrait** mode. I have researched the internet for solution that are able to change the ratio of videos - e.g. Handbrake, Video converter ultimate, Quicktime Pro. However, I cannot figure out how to change the video dimensions properly so that it can play fine on an iPhone 5/6 screen without either extending the picture too much or leaving black fields on top and bottom.

Do you have any ideas how a maximum area of the picture is shown in portrait mode with minimizing loss?

Thank you so much for your great help in advance!

p.s. I have researched as much as possible and found only this topic as similar: [iPhone Background Video](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/16042/iphone-background-video?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can identify a vertical section of the video in the shape you need, that you can crop out of the horizontal image, perhaps panning the 'window' to follow the central action. If you can't then you're stuck with severe letterboxing (blank portions top and bottom). There's no magic that can preserve aspect ratio while changing aspect ratio. Physics... dammit.

Comment: Hello Jim. Thank you for your contribution. Imagine the following video in the lands. mode - footballer kicks the ball in the very left part of the screen and on the right side the ball is in the net in the next second. Physics put serious bounds for showing the ball shot and goal in portrait mode without letterbox on top and bottom. That is why I think the following solution should be the right one (if applicable):

- is it possible with Adobe Premiere or Aftter Effects or ... to mark an object (e.g. the ball) in one frame and to keep this object always in picture although the portrait mode?

Comment: @query_question  I don't know enough to answer that, but if you post a more targeted question, like "Can I crop while tracking an object in AE or Premiere?" and add the tags for Premiere and After Effects, you'll get attention from more people who follow those tags. Good luck.